# How to use an array in for-next to paste values to specific range?

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop, iteration, range

I'm pretty new to using arrays and honestly don't know if that's what I need here. Below is some code that is currently working in my macro that copies and pastes a month in date format across a specified range. X represents the number of periods(months). Note everything below has been simplified to make easier for understanding. The range calc uses the month periods to determine the range, then the portion [value from array] is where i need help. Basically, for for each month below, there are 10 values in the array that need to be pasted in. For example, Jan 2017 has 100 rows of data total, I need the 10 values in the array to each fill in 10 rows for January filling the 100 rows, then move to the next month. Let's say the array range is "A1:A10" for reference. Thanks much!

```
For x = 1 To 3
If Cells(3, 1) = "" Then
Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3162, 1)).Value = [value from array]
End If
Next x
```

Comment: `Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3162, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(array)`

Comment: Thanks. Where to I tell it to paste each value in the array 10x?

Comment: You will need to loop through the array and paste each value ten times then move down tens rows and paste the next.  There is no quick method to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Start with this:

```
    Sub foo()
Dim arr()
arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
With ActiveSheet
    j = 3
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        .Range(.Cells(j, 1), .Cells(j + 9, 1)).Value = arr(i)
        j = j + 10
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```